# Will the Warden run away?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I figured out that the Warden is afraid of silverfish and silverfish infested blocks. Will he run away if I put a silverfish in a boat?

Answer (score 1):

I tried in a survival world, and he quite instantly pointed me and hit me so hard... no matter the boats.

[image: Warden hitting me]

I'm wondering, are you sure the Warden is afraid of Silverfish? Because the only post stating that is actually from [Minecraft Feedback](https://feedback.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/community/posts/4461994950157-warden-is-afraid-of-silverfish):

> When a Silverfish gets too close to the Warden, he gets afraid of the Silverfish,                                        and then he lets out a cry of fear and runs quickly away.
> In these process, the Warden do not attack the player, for a short time.
> The Warden can feel the silverfish in infested stones, and avoids going near them.

..which is a suggestion and not a real feature. As far as I know, because he killed every other Silverfish around without batting an eyelash.
And me, by the way.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I really thought it was true. I love minecraft but don't have it. otherwise I'd test it myself. If you have any questions I would be happy to answer them. I know a lot about minecraft, but I just learned the silverfish thing. sad it's fake.

Comment: That would be a nice idea. Though no Silverfish spawn in Dark biome, so it would be difficult to make them meet, anyway